# VBA. Search a value X in column and copy a part of the row with the X and below ones in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm learning vba and I'm stuck with this:

I have a button that moves an "X" (text) across the A column (sheet1) every time you click the button.

Well, now I would like to make the button to also be able to copy some columns (B,C,D,F) of the "X marked" row and the next four below, and paste it on sheet2 and sheet3.

Comment: You just need to know how to copy ranges to other sheets?

Comment: Yes. i was using: Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E4:E8").value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E15:E19").value but i cant make it work with the if